# Правильно ли сделан адаптив данного блока?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, frontend, адаптивная-верстка

И вообще можно ли это назвать адаптивом? Представьте, что я ваш злейший враг и что вам хочется оскорбить каждую мелочь, где я что-то не так сделал. Спасибо

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gilroy-Bold';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Gilroy-Bold'), url('Gilroy-Bold.woff') format('woff');
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 50;
}

.header__container {
  border: 1px double black;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  min-height: 33px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 0px, 15px;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.menu-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.menu-item {
  display: flex;
  font-family: 'Gilroy-Bold';
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0px 155px 0px 0px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.menu-item:last-child {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

._container {
  border: 1px double black;
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 0px, 15px;
}

@media (max-width: 960px) {
  ._container {
    max-width: 710px;
  }
  .menu-item {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0px 120px 0px 0px;
  }
  .menu-item:last-child {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 766px) {
  ._container {
    max-width: none;
  }
  .menu-item {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0px 125px 0px 0px;
  }
  .menu-item:last-child {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header class="header">
      <div class="header__container _container">
        <div class="menu">
          <ul class="menu-list">
            <li class="menu-item">Home</li>
            <li class="menu-item">About me</li>
            <li class="menu-item">Skills</li>
            <li class="menu-item">Portfolio</li>
            <li class="menu-item">Contacts</li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `margin: 0px 155px 0px 0px;` зачем? Используйте `gap`.

Comment: ой это вроде флексбокс) а я только на нативном ки эс эс пока пишу

Comment: У вас в коде используется флекбокс..

Comment: 1) не корректная запись ```padding: 0px, 15px;```. Запятая лишняя. 2) зачем для ```header``` использовать  ```position: absolute;``` ? 3) вместо ```.menu-item:last-child {margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;}``` --> ```.menu-item:last-child {margin-right: 0;}```, аналогично для подобных стилей 4) для сброса стилей лучше использовать https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: Да, у меня флексбокс используется, но я сейчас верстаю вместе с ютубером, я знаю лишь основы, а в сам флексбокс пока не погружался полностью

Comment: спасибо большое за критику, она очень полезна

Comment: Обычно на 960px уже бургер ставится. Очень большое расстояние между ссылками. Советую сразу изучать флексы. А так смотри видео, повторяй, развивайся, удачи.

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Неправильно. About me переносится, хотя места в строке предостаточно.

Comment: Самая маленькая мобилка вроде в разрешении 320 на что-то там, а в данном случае разрешение экрана где-то на 100 пикселях, является ли это важной вещью?